# How to arrange questions and answers left and right like table data in table using PDFKit in PDF file

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit

The code below is loading dynamic question and answer respectively in PDF using PDFKit.
My output is:

```
question                             answer
```

But I want like:

```
Question.............................answer
```

My code is:

```
pdf.fontSize(12);      
pdf.text(field.field_title, {
  align: 'left',
  lineBreak: true
});
pdf.fontSize(10);
pdf.text(claimData.claimData[0].answers[0][field.field_id], {
  align: 'right',
  lineBreak: true
});
```

Comment: I guess setting lineBreak to false will align it as left and right

Comment: @VinodLouis it is not